# Как настроить контекстное меню на Си(в консоли), чтобы при достижении определенного case выводил обратно в главное меню

Tags: c, меню

```
printf("Enter any character to display the menu.\n");
char a = getchar();
scanf("%s", &a);
system("clear");
printf("1)Start testing\n"
         "2)Instructions for working with the program\n"
         "3)Exit application\n");
char b = getchar();
scanf("%s", &b);
if (!isdigit(b)) {
    printf("Error");
    exit(0);
}
else {
    switch (b) {
```

Как сделать, чтобы при прочтении инструкции, пользователь ввел любой символ/символы и вернулся в главное меню? Через goto делается довольно просто, но пока я читал о нем меня уберегали от его использования очень яростно.

```
case '2':
        system("clear");
        printf("Тут будет инстуркция по работе, ее надо прорабоать\n");
        scanf("%s",&b); //тут попробовал чтобы вводил символы, при введения одного символа не работает
        break;
```

Comment: Вопрос чтобы распознать один символ без ввода или без `goto`?

Comment: Без goto как это сделать? 
Например так человек прочитал инструкцию и будет написано введите любые символы(в том числе и 1), чтобы выйти в главное меню. У меня странности с ведением, если вводить 1 русский символ, то главное меню открывается, если английский или цифру то приходится повторно еще ввести

Comment: Вы в `scanf` показываете указатель на `char`, а `scanf` пишет строку туда. Происходит порча памяти. Буфер бы туда побольше.

Answer (score 1):

Если программа не помещается визуально не экран, обычно советуют использовать переменные состояния продолжать или нет. И использовать цикл `do{..}while(..);`

```
bool contin ;
do {
  contin = false ;
  printf("Enter any character to display the menu.\n");
  char a = getchar();
  scanf("%s", &a);
  system("clear");
  printf("1)Start testing\n"
         "2)Instructions for working with the program\n"
         "3)Exit application\n");
  char b = getchar();
  char buf[16];
  scanf("%s", &buf[0]);
  b = buf[0];
  if (!isdigit(b)) {
    printf("Error");
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    switch (b) {
    case '2':
        system("clear");
        printf("Тут будет инстуркция по работе, ее надо прорабоать\n");
        //тут попробовал чтобы вводил символы, при введения одного символа не работает
        scanf("%s", &buf[0]);
        b = buf[0];
        contin = true ;
        break;
    }
  }
} while ( contin ) ;
```

Comment: Не особо понял как это расположится в коде, что делает например в конце
while(contin); , у нас же стоит там ";" то есть цикла не будет так такогого.
Если понадобиться весь код, то вот https://repl.it/@yaroslav123/SpeedyLimegreenPlots

Comment: Почитайте про циклы здесь : https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/do-while-statement-c?view=vs-2019  В вашей проге `char b = getchar();` уберите `getchar`, вы пользуетесь `scanf`. @RumeOne